# Is there something like LocalizedToNormalized filter in ZF2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have an input which get validated localized with float validator. How can I normalize the value via filter to store in a table which has always the same format?

Answer (score 5):

[NumberFormat](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.filter.set.html#numberformat) might be useful as it includes logic for internationalization

```
$filter = new \Zend\I18n\Filter\NumberFormat("de_DE");
echo $filter->filter(1234567.8912346);
// Returns "1.234.567,891"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want. You can use a callback filter to make 5,85 to 5.85.

```
           array(
                'name' => 'Callback',
                'options' => array(
                    'callback' => function($value) {

                        return str_replace(',', '.', $value);
                    },
                ),
            ),
```

You can modify it to your needs.

Comment: No, sorry. It is a bit more complex. E.g. in german you use a point a thousands separator and a comma as decimal separator. You can't just replace it like this because you have to consider the various formats.